# How to set a default application font to custom font in Android?

Tags: android, text, fonts

Android Oreo introduced a new way to set [custom fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html). But the official documentation page does not mention how to set some custom font to be default across the whole application.

We have theme attributes like `android:textColorPrimary` etc which allow to globally set some default typography related propertis.

Is there something like this available for a new custom font feature?
If yes is it backported by support library to be used on devices below 8.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I'v used it with my app theme:

[image]

And in your app theme just add it as a fontFamily:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   . . . ...
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/demo</item>
</style>
```

Currently it's worked on **8.0 until 4.1 API Jelly Bean** And that's a wide range.

Comment: do you know how to change it programmatically (without 3rd party library)?